# Wicket 1.5.12 redirect page in AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have a modal window in Jquery which is the same as in other applications within the company.

After the user has clicked OK the required Ajax request with the desired parameters work as expected. But within AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior I cannot return a redirect successfully to load another Wicket page.

```
mount(new UnversionedPageMapper("/monitoring", Monitoring.class));
```

In the AjaxButton onSubmit this worked fine but then my Jquery Modal window is passed.

```
new AjaxButton("verwijderenButton", form) { @Override protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) { //setResponsePage(Monitoring.class); } } };
```

The problem is that in AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior where the incoming Ajax call is captured the setResponsePage(Monitoring.class); is not working.
The generated URL is:
https://localhost:9443/monitoring (base name is missing)

```
private final class PanelResponseBejavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {          

        System.out.println("ajax request received Parameters rapportNr "+hsr.getParameter("rapportNr"));
                getSession().info("File '" + rapportDefinitie.getFileName()+ "' is removed

        //requestCycle.setResponse(Monitoring.class);           
                     //verwijderenButton.setEnabled(true);

        //setResponsePage(Monitoring.class);
        //HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) requestCycle.getResponse().getContainerResponse();       
        //requestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RedirectRequestHandler("/lpv/monitoring"));           
        //requestCycle.getResponse().close();


        //target.addComponent(getPage()); 
                throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(Monitoring.class);
    }
```

With HttpServletResponse and requestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent i get no errors page is found by the server and returned because this gives the desired url but the browser do not load the page.
https://localhost:9443/APP/LPV/monitoring

Here is my Javascript

```html
$('#dialogVerwijderen').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true, 
      buttons: {
                 OK: function() {                   
                     $.ajax({
                           url:callbackUrl,
                           type: "POST", 
                           cache: false,                          
                              data: "action=remove&rapportNr="+rapportNr,                             
                              success: function () {                               
                               alert(" button");
                              }                              
                     })
                   
                 },
                 Cancel: function() {
                     $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                    }
              },
     resizable: false,
     closeOnEscape: true, 
     open: function() {
      $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Cancel')").focus();  
        }
     });             
});
```

Perhaps it is easier in JS to req for the Wicket page but the Wicket Url can be tricky.

**My question is how can I send a redirect in "AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior" After the user has confirmed to another Wicket page with all Wicket stuff as FeedbackPanel etc ?**

Comment: For now I have a solution in Javascript like this.

Comment: success: function (data) {                               
                            window.location.href =appNm;
                          },